# What is the derived set of $A=\{1,\frac12,\ldots,\frac1n,\ldots\}$ in $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Please how to find $A'$ where $A=\{1,\frac12,\ldots,\frac1n,\ldots\}$

i know that $x\in A' \Longleftrightarrow \forall V\in \mathcal{V}_x, V\setminus\{x\}\cap A \neq \emptyset$ but i dont know how to apply this to the given $A$ .

Thank you

Comment: Is $99$ in $A'$?

Comment: No ! $99\notin A'$ @Christoph

Comment: So you know how to apply the definition. What about $1$, is it in $A'$?

Comment: if i take $V=]1-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon[$ nghb of 1 than i think that for all $\varepsilon>0$ $]1-\varepsilon,1[\cup]1,1+\varepsilon[\cap A\neq \emptyset$ so i think that $1\in A'$ @Christoph

Comment: @Vrouvrou Think again with $\epsilon=\frac12$

Comment: Take $\varepsilon=\frac 1 2$, does $(1-\frac 1 2, 1+\frac 1 2)\setminus \{1\}$ intersect $A$?

Comment: $]\frac12,1[\cup]1,\frac32[ \cap A=\emptyset$ yes

Comment: Yes @Christoph but $\frac12 \in A'$ no ?

Comment: So you concluded $1\notin A'$, right? For $\frac 1 2$, what about $V=(\frac 1 2 - \frac 1 {100}, \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 {100})$?

Comment: Thant's right $\frac12\notin A'$ but who is in $A'$? @Christoph and how i can made a proof

Comment: Well, who has points arbitrarily close to it in $A$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30472/discussion-between-vrouvrou-and-christoph).

Comment: please how to prove mathematicaly that all the points of $A$ are isolated points ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A'=\{0\}$.

For any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\dfrac1{n}\in A$ and $\dfrac1{n}<\epsilon$, i.e. $\dfrac1{n}\in(0,\epsilon)=V_0$ ($V_0$ is open). All other points in $A$ are isolated points, i.e. for any $n$, there is a $\,\epsilon>0\,$ such that
$$
\left(\dfrac1{n}-\epsilon,\dfrac1{n}+\epsilon\right)\cap \left(A-\left\{\dfrac1{n}\right\}\right)=\varnothing\tag1
$$

**Edit:**

Consider any point $\dfrac1{n}\in A$. Since $\left\{\dfrac1{n}\right\}$ is monotonic decreasing, the closest point to its left is $\dfrac1{n+1}$ and the closest point to its right is $\dfrac1{n-1}$. Let
$$
\epsilon<\min{\left(\frac1{n}-\frac1{n+1},\frac1{n-1}-\frac1{n}\right)}=\frac1{(n+1)n}
$$ Then for any $\dfrac1{k}\in A, \:k\ne n$
$$
\left|\dfrac1{k}-\dfrac1{n}\right|>\epsilon\quad\text{and so }\quad \dfrac1{k}\notin \left(\dfrac1{n}-\epsilon,\dfrac1{n}+\epsilon\right) 
$$
So $(1)$ holds and $\dfrac1{n}$ is an isolated point.

Comment: I dont understand your answer

Comment: please how to prove mathematicaly that all the points of $A$ are isolated points ?

Comment: yes i understand it thank you

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$.

So let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary.

Thus there is $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for each $n>N$ , $|\frac{1}{n}-0|<\epsilon$ .

So we have that $0\in A'$ .

Now observe that $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\geq\frac{1}{n(n+n)}\geq\frac{1}{2n^2}$

So whenever you pick a point you can find an open set such that it does not have non empty intersection with $A$.

So $A'$ contains only $0$.

Comment: I dont understand this part :Now observe that $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\geq\frac{1}{n(n+n)}\geq\frac{1}{2n^2}$ what we do with this? please

Comment: It's not necessary. I just used it to show that we can find empty gaps in between points of $A$

Comment: that  is what i don't understand how we see this using $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\geq\frac{1}{n(n+n)}\geq\frac{1}{2n^2‌​}$

Comment: please can you explain me

Comment: Just take a pencil. Draw the inteval $(0,1)$ and mark all pionts in $A$. Then you will see that more closer you get to $0$ the distance between two consecutive points get even more closer. So zero is limit point and for any other point in $A$ you can draw an open interval without intersecting any other point.

Comment: I understand this but i dont understand the $\frac1n-\frac{1}{n+1}\geq \frac{1}{2n^2}$ in what it help us ?

Answer (score 1):

$0$ is the only limit point, which exactly this sequence goest to.